# INDEX/MATCH only finds the first value in a column with multiple entries

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Column A has a list of values which need to be matched with Column B. If matched, the adjacent values in Column C should be returned. I'm using INDEX/MATCH to perform this action. However, if Column A has a value which is repeated, the INDEX/MATCH function returns the first value from Column B rather than the 2nd or 3rd value being looked-up in Column B. Is it possible to find the other values (except the 1st one) in Column B using the INDEX/MATCH function?

Here's the sample table:

```
    Column A            Column B            Column C
    lookup0x16e663000   lookup0x16e663000   1461178793193312
    lookup0x16e663001   lookup0x16e663000   1461178793193508
    lookup0x16e663000   lookup0x16e663001   1461178793193704
    lookup0x16e663001   lookup0x16e663001   1461178793193891
    lookup0x16e663000   lookup0x16e663005   1461178793194110
    lookup0x16e663005   lookup0x16e663005   1461178793194312
    lookup0x16e663005   lookup0x16e663000   1461178793194538
    lookup0x16e663000   lookup0x16e663000   1461178793194760
```

So here, if I look for the 4th value from Column A, it matches with the 3rd value of Column B rather than the 4th.

Comment: Not with INDEX/MATCH you will need to incorporate a LARGE or AGGREGATE in place of MATCH to return the proper row number.  If you post some example data and expected outcome we may be able to help further.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've made edits to my question and added the table here. How can we use the Large or Aggregate function? I've never used it before. Here's what I'm using right now. =INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(A2,B:B,0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the AGGREGATE() Function in place of the MATCH:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$8)/($A$1:$A$8=B1),COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1)))
```

The AGGREGATE(15,6,...) simulates the SMALL(IF()) Function.  The `ROW($A$1:$A$8)/($A$1:$A$8=B1)` creates an array of row numbers where B1 = $A$1:$A$8.

The COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,B1) will tell the AGGREGATE() Function which of that array of row numbers to return. As it is dragged down the count will change from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on.

[image]

As per your comment this formula Is dynamic to limit the reference data to the extents of Column A.

The `INDEX(C:C,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))` returns the last row in column C where there is data in Column A

Put this in D2 and copy down.

```
=INDEX($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)))/($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))=B2),COUNTIF($B$1:$B2,B2)))
```

**Edit 2**

I apparently had my column reversed.

Put this in D2 and copy down.

```
=INDEX($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)))/($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))=A2),COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Getting a #NUM error when I use the formula you mentioned. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have more data in the table. Therefore, I cannot define the end of the column. Here's what I'm using: =INDEX($C:$C, AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=B2),COUNTIF($B:$B,B2)))

Comment: First do not use full column references, an array formula calculates exponentially and you will kill excel.  The problem is the count if.  It has to be exactly like this for Row 2 `COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)` Note what is and what is not relative.  It will only count those that are above it.  Give me a second and I will rework the formula to be dynamic in finding the last row of the data. @harry71152

Comment: @harry71152 see edit.  REmember that when we get this working to mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: this works partially. It returns the values, but they're not in order. Even if you look at the table you posted, the first 4 values are correct, but the next 3 are wrong. Same thing happens with the edited formula, it gives values, but they're not in the correct order

Comment: @harry71152 what order should they be in?  The fifth line is the first `lookup0x16e663005` and the sixth is the second.  So what order do you want them.  It is in order as they appear, do you want them in order of value in C?

Comment: Upvote just for doing all this work XD Edit: well, all this work probably took you half a second but still =P

Comment: The 5th line of Column A is 3rd instance of lookup0x16e663000, but the 5th line of Column D is returned as 6th line of Column C, instead of the 7th line bcoz the 3rd instance of the above mentioned is the 7th line of Column B. So, Column D should appear in the same order as Column A.

Comment: Okay I think I have it I had Column A and B backwards give me a second. @harry71152

Comment: @harry71152 FWIW, next time please post not only the data but the expected outcome.  It would have helped show that I had understood the direction of the lookup wrong.  I hope that we have it correct.  If not let me know.

Comment: Works like a charm!!! You ROCK!!! I've tried to upvote so many times but I guess I don't have enough reputation to give upvotes yet!! But, you did an amazing job!! Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: @ScottCraner...sorry, but I had another question. It might be a stupid one. Can I use this formula in a macro? I'm getting a syntax error when I try to insert this formula in a cell using macro.

Comment: @harry71152 see my answer there.